# Initialize 2D array of objects

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

Hi I am having a problem with the initialization of a 2D array of objects.
The class is   `TermFrequency(Key,string,int,double);`
That's how I initialize the dynamic 2D array of objects:

```
// TermFrequency tfreq [v_word.size()][totalNumberOfDocuments];
   TermFrequency** tfreq = new TermFrequency*[v_word.size()];
   for(size_t i = 0; i < v_word.size(); ++i)
       tfreq[i] = new TermFrequency[totalNumberOfDocuments];
```

I understood why i am getting the error:

- no matching function for call to 'TermFrequency::TermFrequency()'|
- note: TermFrequency::TermFrequency(Key, std::string, int, double)|

I just want to know how I can fix it?

Thank you.

Ok I added the **DEFAULT**  Constructor TermFrequency and it worked:`TermFrequency();`
Now for example I can add new objects like, right?

Is that implementation considered right?

```
 For(int i = 0; i < Length1; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < length2;j++){
       tfreq[i][j] = TermFrequency(v_word[i],documents[j],j,wordCount);
    }
    }
```

And that's for the output:

```
  for( size_t i = 0 ; i < v_word.size() ; i++ )
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < totalNumberOfDocuments;j++)
        {
             cout << tfreq[i][j].getTermFrequency() << endl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Compiler do not provide default constructor when you have overloaded it.

Comment: In response to your edit, yes, you can do that. Or you can use a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead to make things easier.

Comment: Yes one more Thing hmmm I tried tfreq[i][j]->getTermFrequency() instead of tfreq[i][j].getTermFrequency() and it gave me an error can u explain it why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
TermFrequency tfreq[v_word.size()][totalNumberOfDocuments];
```

attempts to default-construct an array of `TermFrequency` objects. In other words, it will call the default-constructor of all the elements in the array.

The problem is that your `TermFrequency` class already has a user-defined constructor (`TermFrequency::TermFrequency(Key, std::string, int, double)` that overrides the compiler-generated default-constructor. You'll need to include it on your own:

```
class TermFrequency
{
    public:
         TermFrequency() { ... }
    // ...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace this

```
tfreq[i] = new TermFrequency[totalNumberOfDocuments];
```

with this

```
tfreq[i] = new TermFrequency(yourKey,totalNumberOfDocuments);
```

or simply

```
 tfreq[i] = //create new TeamFrequencyObject by using class constructor
```

Comment: I added a default constructor @Nikola to initialize the array. what am i doing is right?

Comment: @HaniGoc yes, you can test it

Answer (score 1):

> > no matching function for call to 'TermFrequency::TermFrequency()

It looks like your class doesn't have a default constructor and then the line

```
tfreq[i] = new TermFrequency[totalNumberOfDocuments];
```

fails to compile.

Comment: Ahh. Well i have this contructor TermFrequency(Key,string,int,double);
Do i need a default constructor? Sorry if this question is silly

Comment: Yes, you do need a default constructor: one that accepts an empty list of arguments. Normally the compiler defines one for you but if you define another constructor (as you do) then the compiler will not generate the default constructor and you have to do it manually.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have overloaded your conctructor `TermFrequency(Key,string,int,double);` you do not have a default one anymore. And when you call this line

`tfreq[i] = new TermFrequency[totalNumberOfDocuments];`

your program looks for a default constructor.

In order to avoid the error you have to rewrite your overlaoded `TermFrequency` constructor as follows:

`TermFrequency(Key = Key(),string = " ",int = 0,double = 0);`

Answer (score 1):

or **Dynamic** then you can do the following :

```
myclass **mc =  new myclass*[5];
 for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) 
  mc[i] = new myclass[6];
```

then you can for loop the 2d mc[i][x] = new myclass ( ); // if you have several constructors , if you have the default one then the previous first loop is enough without calling the constructor in each element , it will be called by default

what i meant is that if you have two constructors

```
myclass (){
 this->variable = 0 //... etc
}
```

and another constructor

```
myclass (int var){
 this->variable = var;
}
```

if you want all elements to be initialized by the second constructor , then you need to for loop each element like i said :D